# C# - Connection always open - how to open-close

Tags: c#, connection

I need some help with a application.
The application is running 24/7, but if the connection to the database is missing, then the application no longer works - it just stops.

It looks like the connection is never closed, but I don't know why.

Would it be possible to make this application more robust to database offline?
What to do :o)

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel;
    using System.Data;
    using System.Data.OleDb;
    using System.Drawing;
    using System.IO;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Windows.Forms;
    using System.Xml;
    using System.Windows;
    using System.Runtime;
    using System.Drawing.Printing;
    using cs_IniHandlerDevelop;

    namespace AlServ_Batch
    {

public partial class Batch_MainForm : Form
{


    public Batch_MainForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Batch_MainForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        UpdateStatusLight();           
    }

    private void UpdateStatusLight() {
        ConnectionState st = Connection.State;
        if (st == ConnectionState.Open
            || st == ConnectionState.Fetching
            || st == ConnectionState.Executing
            )
        {
            pictureBox1.Image = Properties.Resources.greenlight;
        }
        else if (st == ConnectionState.Closed || st == ConnectionState.Broken)
        {
            pictureBox1.Image = Properties.Resources.redlight;
        }
        else
        {
            pictureBox1.Image = Properties.Resources.yellowlight;
        }
    }

    public static string[] TextTypeName = new string[] { "", 
        "Portvagt/I normal arbejdstid", 
        "TDA/I normal arbejdstid underret", 
        "Portvagt/Uden for normal arbejdstid", 
        "TDA/Uden for normal arbejdstid", 
        "Procedure", 
        "Anlæg og følerplacering", 
        "Særlige forhold", 
        "Betjeningsområde", //***//
        "Anden instruktion (SOP/BPP)", 
        "System Alarm"}; //***//

    public static string[] TextFieldName = new string[] { "", 
        "workcall", "workinform", "offcall", "offinform", "procedur", 
        "plant", "turnoff", "position", "instruction", "restart" };

    private int timerLevel = 0;

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (timerLevel == 0)
        {
            timerLevel++;
            try
            {
                UpdateStatusLight();
                ProcessBatch();
            }
            catch { }
            timerLevel--;
        }
    }

    private void ProcessBatch()
    {
        if (Connection.State == ConnectionState.Open)
        {
            {
                String sql = "select recid,action,parm1,parm2,parm3,parm4,targetfile from alarm.batch where recid>0 order by recid";
                OleDbCommand cmd = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand(sql, Connection);
                OleDbDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                if (reader.Read())
                {
                    int n = 0;
                    string recid_str = reader[n++].ToString();
                    string action = reader[n++].ToString();
                    string parm1 = reader[n++].ToString();
                    string parm2 = reader[n++].ToString();
                    string parm3 = reader[n++].ToString();
                    string parm4 = reader[n++].ToString();
                    string targetfile = reader[n++].ToString();

                    sql = "update alarm.batch set recid= -" + recid_str + " where recid=" + recid_str;
                    cmd = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand(sql, Connection);
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                    if (ProcessBatchItem(action, parm1, parm2, parm3, parm4, targetfile))
                    {
                        sql = "delete from alarm.batch where recid= -" + recid_str;
                        cmd = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand(sql, Connection);
                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    }
                }
                reader.Close();

            }
        }

    }

    private bool ProcessBatchItem(string action, string parm1, string parm2, string parm3, string parm4, string targetfile)
    {
        DateTime waituntil;
        bool res = true;
        bool liveAlarm = false;
        string fname = "";
        string fnameTemp;
        string targetPrinters = "";
        if (targetfile.ToString().Length>0) {
            fname = Path.Combine(Properties.Settings.Default.htmlprintpath, targetfile);
        }
        TextWriter tw;

        if (fname == "") fname = (new Random()).Next(int.MaxValue) + "__" + (new Random()).Next(int.MaxValue) + ".htm";

        fnameTemp = fname + "_";
        tw = new StreamWriter(fnameTemp);
        string htmlPrefix = "<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd\">"
                            ;
        AlarmInstruction instruction = new AlarmInstruction();
        if (action == "print")
        {
            liveAlarm = (parm4=="ALARM");
            instruction = new AlarmInstruction(int.Parse(parm1), Connection);
            targetPrinters = instruction.TargetPrinters;
            WriteAlarmInstruction(tw, instruction, parm3+(targetPrinters.Length>0 ? " ("+targetPrinters+")":""), parm2.ToString()=="1", parm4, htmlPrefix+"<body charset=windows-1252>", "</body>");
            tw.Close();
        }
        else if (action == "printmany")
        {
            WriteAlarmInstructions(tw, parm1,parm3,parm4,htmlPrefix+"<body charset=windows-1252>", "</body>");
            liveAlarm = false; // (parm4 == "ALARM");
            tw.Close();
        }
        System.IO.File.Move(fnameTemp, fname);
        if (liveAlarm || true) {

            string ts = DateTime.Now.ToString();
            bool busy = true;

            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(fname);
            string docText = reader.ReadToEnd();

            foreach (char ch in targetPrinters)
            {
                try
                {
                    int n = int.Parse(ch.ToString());
                    n = n == 0 ? 10 : n;
                    if (n > 0 && n <= 10)
                    {
                            HtmlPrint(docText, instruction.PrinterName(n));
                    }
                }
                catch
                {
                }
            }

            foreach (string mobile in instruction.SmsTarget.Split(new char[] { ';'}))
            {
                try
                {
                    string smsDir = instruction.Ini.GetValue("Directory", "Sms");
                    string footer = instruction.Ini.GetValue("Sms", "Footer");
                    fname = smsDir + "\\" + DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString();
                    fnameTemp = fname + ".$$$";
                    tw = new StreamWriter(fnameTemp);
                    tw.WriteLine(mobile);
                    tw.WriteLine();
                    tw.WriteLine(parm3);
                    tw.WriteLine(instruction.UserAdr);
                    tw.WriteLine(instruction.Caption);
                    tw.WriteLine(footer);
                    tw.Close();
                    File.Move(fnameTemp, fname + ".txt");
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                }
            }


        }
        waituntil = DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(2);
        while (DateTime.Now < waituntil) Application.DoEvents();
        return res;
    }

    private void HtmlPrint(string doctext, string printerName)
    {
        Batch_BrowserForm browserForm = new Batch_BrowserForm();
        browserForm.Show();
        browserForm.PrintHtml(doctext, printerName, this);
    }

    private string magic = "gkhjagdsfgkjhgkjhasdfyehecghgefuuweyuyjhweuyg1233498712vcgdqssedrrggggg";
    private string InstructionTextRow(int textId, string title, string caption, bool optional)
    {
        string res;
        NumberedText txt = new NumberedText(textId,Connection);
        if (txt.Text=="" && optional) {
            res = "";
        } else {
            res = "<tr><td valign=top>"
                + (title.ToString().Length > 0 ? "<b>" + xmlencode(title.Replace(" ", magic)).Replace(magic, "&nbsp;") + "</b><br/>" : "")
                + xmlencode(caption) + "</td><td valign=top width=1%>" + (txt.Id > 0 ? "<div width=100% style=\"border: gainsboro 1px solid\">" + txt.Id.ToString() + "</div>&nbsp;" : "") + "</td><td valign=top borderwidth=1 style=\"border: gainsboro 1px solid\" width=80%>" + xmlencode(txt.Text.ToString()).Replace("\n", "&nbsp;<br/>").Replace("\r", "") + "&nbsp;</td></tr>";
        }
        return res;
    }

    public string xmlencode(string s)
    {
        XmlDocument xmldoc = new XmlDocument();
        XmlNode xn = xmldoc.CreateElement("data");
        xn.InnerText = s;
        return xn.InnerXml;
    }

    private string FrameDivRight(string s)
    {
        return "<div halign=right style=\"border: lavender 1px solid\">" + xmlencode(s) + "</div>";
    }

    private string FramedText(string caption, string s)
    {
        return "<table width=100%><tr><td><i>" + xmlencode(caption.Replace(" ", magic)).Replace(magic, "&nbsp;") + "&nbsp;</td><td width=100% style=\"border: gray 1px solid\">" + (s.ToString().Length > 0 ? xmlencode(s) : "&nbsp;") + "</i></td></tr></table>";
    }

    private string CondFramedText(string caption, string s)
    {
        return (s.Length > 0) ? FramedText(caption, s) : "&nbsp;";
    }

    private string rowtext(AlarmInstruction instruction, int textidx, string title, bool optional) {
        int textId = instruction.textids[textidx];
        return InstructionTextRow(textId,title,TextTypeName[textidx],optional);
    }

    private void WriteAlarmInstructions(TextWriter textwriter, string whereclause, string timestamp, string qualification, string prefix, string postfix)
    {
        //String sql = "select id from alarm.point"+(String.IsNullOrEmpty(whereclause) ? "": " where "+whereclause)+" order by useradr";
        String sql = (new AlarmInstruction()).BasicSelect + (String.IsNullOrEmpty(whereclause) ? "" : " where " + whereclause) + " order by useradr";
        OleDbCommand cmd = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand(sql, Connection);
        OleDbDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        bool first = true;

        textwriter.Write(prefix);

        while (reader.Read())
        {
            try
            {
                AlarmInstruction instruction = new AlarmInstruction();
                instruction.InitFromReader(reader);

                WriteAlarmInstruction(textwriter, instruction, timestamp, false, qualification, "<div " + (first ? "" : "style=\"page-break-before:always\"") + "></div>", "");
                //textwriter.Write("s=" + s + "<br>");
                first = false;
            }
            catch
            {
            }
        }
        reader.Close();

        textwriter.Write(postfix);
    }

    private bool WriteAlarmInstruction(TextWriter textwriter, AlarmInstruction instruction, string timestamp, bool alarmTest, string qualification, string prefix, string postfix)
    {

        /*
          textwriter.Write(DateTime.Now.ToString() + " ALARM " + id.ToString() + "<br/>");
          return true
         */

        if (qualification != "ALARM") timestamp = "";

        string pageContents = "";
        pageContents += "<style>TD,P,I,INPUT,DIV{font-family:arial,helvetica; font-size:8pt}</style>";
        pageContents += "<style>B{font-family:arial,helvetica; font-size:10pt}</style>";
        pageContents += "<table cellspacing=3 width=100%><tr><td align=left><h1>"
                        +(alarmTest ? "Alarmafprøvning" : "Alarminstruks")
                        +"</h1></td><td align=right>" + xmlencode(instruction.SystemId + " ").Replace(" ", "&nbsp;") + xmlencode(timestamp) + "</td></tr></table>";
        pageContents += "<table width=100%>";

        pageContents += "<tr><td>" + FramedText("ID nr.", instruction.UserAdr.ToString()) + "</td><td valign=right>" + FramedText("Betegnelse", instruction.Caption) + "</td><td>" + FramedText("Prioritet ", instruction.Notif) + "</td></tr>";
        pageContents += "<tr><td>" + CondFramedText("$ Adr.", instruction.TechAdr.ToString()) + "</td><td valign=right>" + CondFramedText("Alarmgrænse høj", instruction.AlarmLimitHigh.ToString()) + "</td><td>" + CondFramedText("Enhed", instruction.Unit.ToString()) + "</td></tr>";
        pageContents += "<tr><td></td><td valign=right>" + CondFramedText("Alarmgrænse lav", instruction.AlarmLimitLow.ToString()) + "</td><td>" + CondFramedText("Tidsforsinkelse", instruction.TimeDelay.ToString()) + "</td></tr>";
        pageContents += "<tr><td></td><td valign=right>" + FramedText("Alarm GMP kritisk", instruction.GMPCritical.ToString()) + "</td><td>" + FramedText("Kræver alarmen afvigelse (NDP)", instruction.Deviation.ToString()) + "</td></tr>";
        pageContents += "</table>";
        pageContents += "<table cellspacing=3>";

        pageContents += "<tr height=2px><td colspan=3><hr></td></tr>";
        pageContents += "<tr><td>"
                        + FramedText("Bruger afd.",instruction.UserDept)
                        +"</td><td colspan=2>"
                            +"<table><tr><td>"
                            + FramedText("Ansvarlig",instruction.Responsible)
                            +"</td><td>"
                            + FramedText("TDA driftsgruppe",instruction.OperationsGroup)                            
                            +"</td></tr></table>"
                        +"</td></tr>";
        pageContents += "<tr><td colspan=3 height=2px><hr></td></tr>";

        pageContents += rowtext(instruction, 8, "", false);
        pageContents += rowtext(instruction, 6, "", false);
        pageContents += "<tr height=2px><td colspan=3><hr></td></tr>";
        pageContents += rowtext(instruction, 1, "Portvagt aktion/tilkald", false);
        pageContents += rowtext(instruction, 3, "", true);
        pageContents += "<tr height=2px><td colspan=3><hr></td></tr>";
        pageContents += rowtext(instruction, 7, "Aktion TDA", false);
        pageContents += rowtext(instruction, 5, "", false);
        pageContents += rowtext(instruction, 9, "", false);
        pageContents += rowtext(instruction, 2, "Underret bruger", false);
        pageContents += rowtext(instruction, 4, "", true);
        pageContents += rowtext(instruction, 10, "", true);

        if (instruction.UserUpdate.Length > 0)
        {
            pageContents += "<tr><td colspan=2></td><td valign=right><i>" + xmlencode("Instruks opdateret "+ instruction.UserUpdate) + "</i></td></tr>";
        }

        pageContents += "</table>";

        textwriter.Write(prefix+"<table height=100% width=100%><tr><td valign=top>" + pageContents + "</td></tr></table>"+postfix);

        return true;
    }

    public String ConnectionString
    {
        get { return Properties.Settings.Default.ConnectionString; }
    }

    private OleDbConnection con_;
    public OleDbConnection Connection
    {
        get
        {
            if (con_ == null)
            {
                OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(ConnectionString);
                try
                {
                    connection.Open();
                }
                catch
                {
                }
                con_ = connection;
            }
            return con_;
        }
    }

    class AlarmInstruction
    {
        public int Id;
        public string SystemId;
        public string UserAdr;
        public string Caption;
        public string UserDept;
        public string Responsible;
        public string OperationsGroup;
        public string Notif;
        public string NotifMaster;
        public string TechAdr;
        public string AlarmLimitHigh;
        public string AlarmLimitLow;
        public string Unit;
        public string TimeDelay;
        public string GMPCritical;
        public string Deviation;
        public string UserUpdate;
        public string Recipient;

        public int[] textids;

        public DateTime NotifDateTime = new DateTime(0);

        private string _targetPrinters = null;
        public string TargetPrinters
        {
            get {
                try
                {
                    if (_targetPrinters == null)
                    {
                        if (NotifDateTime.CompareTo(new DateTime(0))==0)
                        {
                            NotifDateTime = DateTime.Now;
                        }
                        _targetPrinters = "";
                    }
                    string sql = "select targets,weekday,hour from notifdetail where notifmaster=" + NotifMaster+" order by weekday,hour";
                    OleDbCommand cmd = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand(sql, Connection);
                    OleDbDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                    DateTime now = NotifDateTime;
                    DayOfWeek wd = now.DayOfWeek;
                    int weekday = (wd==DayOfWeek.Sunday ? 7 : 1+(wd-DayOfWeek.Monday));
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        int fromweekday = int.Parse(reader["weekday"].ToString());
                        DateTime fromhour = reader.GetDateTime(reader.GetOrdinal("hour"));

                        if (fromweekday<weekday  || (fromweekday==weekday && (fromhour.TimeOfDay<=now.TimeOfDay) )) 
                        {
                            _targetPrinters = reader["targets"].ToString();
                        }
                    }
                    reader.Close();
                }
                catch
                {
                }
                return _targetPrinters;
            }
        }

        private string _smsTarget = null;
        public string SmsTarget
        {
            get {
                if (_smsTarget == null)
                {
                    if (TargetPrinters.Contains("S") && Recipient.Length>0) {
                        try
                        {
                            string sql = "select mobile from recipients where id="+  (new MySqlLayer()).SqlLit(Recipient);
                            OleDbCommand cmd = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand(sql, Connection);
                            OleDbDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                            while (reader.Read())
                            {
                                _smsTarget = reader["mobile"].ToString();
                            }
                            reader.Close();

                        } 
                        catch 
                        {
                        }
                    }
                }
                if (_smsTarget == null)
                {
                    _smsTarget = "";
                }
                return _smsTarget.Trim(); 
            }
        }

        private IniStructure _ini = null;
        public IniStructure Ini
        {
            get {
                if (_ini == null)
                {
                    _ini = IniStructure.ReadIni("C:\\alarm\\alarm.ini");
                }
                return _ini; 
            }
        }

        public string PrinterName(int n)
        {
            string pname = "";
            try
            {
                pname = Ini.GetValue("Printers", "printer" + n.ToString());
            }
            catch
            {
            }
            if (pname.Length==0) throw new Exception("Printer selection failed. Printer #"+n.ToString()+", name \""+pname+"\"");
            return pname;
        }

        public void InitFromReader(OleDbDataReader reader)
        {
            Id = int.Parse(reader["id"].ToString());
            SystemId = reader["systemid"].ToString();
            UserAdr = reader["useradr"].ToString();
            Caption = reader["descr"].ToString();
            Notif = reader["notifnam"].ToString();
            NotifMaster = reader["notifmaster"].ToString();
            TechAdr = reader["techadr"].ToString();
            Unit = reader["unit"].ToString();
            TimeDelay = reader["timedelay"].ToString();
            AlarmLimitHigh = reader["alarmlimithigh"].ToString();
            AlarmLimitLow = reader["alarmlimitlow"].ToString();
            GMPCritical = reader["gmpcritical"].ToString() == "1" ? "Ja" : "Nej";
            Deviation = reader["deviation"].ToString() == "1" ? "Ja" : "Nej";
            UserUpdate = reader["user_update"].ToString();
            UserDept = reader["dept"].ToString();
            Responsible = reader["userid"].ToString();
            OperationsGroup = reader["operationsgroup"].ToString();
            Recipient = reader["recipient"].ToString();


            int n = TextTypeName.GetUpperBound(0);
            textids = new int[n + 1];

            for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
            {
                try
                {
                    textids[i] = int.Parse(reader[TextFieldName[i]].ToString());
                }
                catch
                {
                    textids[i] = 0;
                };
            }

        }

        public String BasicSelect {
            get {
                return "select *,(select usernam from notifmaster where id= point.notifmaster) notifnam,(select id from alarmsystem) systemid  from alarm.point";
            }
        }

        public AlarmInstruction()
            : base()
        {
        }

        OleDbConnection Connection = null;

        public AlarmInstruction(int id, OleDbConnection connection)
            : base()
        {
            String sql = BasicSelect + " where id=" + id.ToString();
            try
            {
                Connection = connection;
                OleDbCommand cmd = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand(sql, connection);
                OleDbDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                if (reader.Read())
                {
                    InitFromReader(reader);
                }
                reader.Close();
            }
            catch { }

        }
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SQL_performer performer = new SQL_performer();
        performer.Connection = Connection;
        performer.Show();
    }

}

class NumberedText
{
    public NumberedText(int textId, OleDbConnection connection) 
        : base() 
    {
        String sql = "select txt,typ from alarm.txt where id="+textId.ToString();
        OleDbCommand cmd = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand(sql, connection);
        try
        {
            if (textId > 0)
            {
                OleDbDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                if (reader.Read())
                {
                    int n = 0;
                    _Id = textId;
                    _Text = reader[n++].ToString();
                    _Typ = int.Parse(reader[n++].ToString());
                }
                reader.Close();
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            _Error = true;
        }

        if (_Text == null) _Text = "";
        if (_Typ == null) _Typ = 0;
    }

    private DateTime _TimeStamp;
    public DateTime TimeStamp
    {
        get { return _TimeStamp; }
        set { _TimeStamp = value; }
    }

    private bool _Error;
    public bool Error
    {
        get { return _Error; }
    }

    private int _Id;
    public int Id
    {
        get { return _Id; }
    }

    private string _Text;
    public string Text
    {
        get { return _Text; }
    }

    private int _Typ;
    public int Typ
    {
        get { return _Typ; }
    }


}

public class MySqlLayer
{
    public virtual String SqlLit(Object obj)
    {
        if (obj == null)
        {
            return "null";
        }
        else if (obj is string)
        {
            return (String.IsNullOrEmpty(obj as string) ? "null" : ("'" + (obj as string).Replace("'", "''") + "'"));
        }
        else if (obj is int)
        {
            return (obj.ToString());
        }
        else if (obj is DateTime)
        {
            DateTime d = (DateTime)obj;
            return String.Format("TO_DATE('{0:0000}-{1:00}-{2:00} {3:00}:{4:00}','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI')", d.Year, d.Month, d.Day, d.Hour, d.Minute);
        }
        else
        {
            return "null";
        }
    }
}

    }
```

Comment: Don't add an empty `catch-block` as you've done here: `try
                {
                    connection.Open();
                }
                catch
                {
                }`. Always close a connections as soon as you're finished with it with the `using-statemenet`.

Comment: sorry for all the detaisl - but this is not my code. I only try to find a solution to my problem when database is offline.

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is that you should close your connection ASAP.

Here is how I would write the ProcessBatch method:

```
private void ProcessBatch()
{
    using (OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnmection(ConnectionString))
    {
        connection.Open();
        {
            String sql = "select recid,action,parm1,parm2,parm3,parm4,targetfile from alarm.batch where recid>0 order by recid";
            OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(sql, connection);
            using (OleDbDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                if (reader.Read())
                {
                    int n = 0;
                    string recid_str = reader[n++].ToString();
                    string action = reader[n++].ToString();
                    string parm1 = reader[n++].ToString();
                    string parm2 = reader[n++].ToString();
                    string parm3 = reader[n++].ToString();
                    string parm4 = reader[n++].ToString();
                    string targetfile = reader[n++].ToString();

                    sql = "update alarm.batch set recid= -" + recid_str + " where recid=" + recid_str;
                    cmd = new OleDbCommand(sql, connection);
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                    if (ProcessBatchItem(action, parm1, parm2, parm3, parm4, targetfile))
                    {
                        sql = "delete from alarm.batch where recid= -" + recid_str;
                        cmd = new OleDbCommand(sql, connection);
                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Note that the using-statement automatically closes the connection when the ProcessBatch is finished.  If E.g. ProcessBatchItem requires a connection you should hand over the connection as a parameter.

You might also consider using a OleDbTransation.

In your application you should remove the Connection-property.

Good luck with your application.

Comment: thank you very much. will try this tomorrow...